# Problems connecting Samsung Galaxy S2 to computer

Tags: android

I've got a Samsung Galaxy S2 and am taking an android development class. For the past two months, I've been using the emulator to run the activity.

Recently, I've been trying to get it connected to my device. Now, the drivers are installed on my computer as I can see the device (and view the files) through "My Computer" (Windows 7 Professional). However, using something like

> adb devices

does not show the device, nor through the app launcher in eclipse (when choosing between a virtual device or connected one).

Any help on trying to get it recognized by adb?

Some misc. things:

- the model is SPH-D710
- I've enabled USB debugging from the phone

Answer (score 0):

OP here, through some help on #android (on freenode), I was able to get this fixed.

The steps I took were,

1. Remove all pre-existing drivers
2. I installed a universal driver linked by: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1514942

And it worked after that.

Thanks davieslacker